# Laravel - Eager Loading - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

Sorry for the noob question, but I am not able to make eager loading work, and instead getting: `Trying to get property of non-object` in my view (`index.blade.php` below).

**Users table**

```
id | first_name | other_columns
```

**Credits table**

```
id | recipient | other_columns
```

`recipient` is `id` from the Users table.

**Credit.php**

```
class Credit extends Model {
    public function recipient() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'recipient');
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
class User extends Model {
    public function credits() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Credit', 'recipient');
    }
}
```

**CreditController.php**

```
class CreditController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $credits = Credit::with('recipient')->get();
        return view('pages.credits.index')->withCredits($credits);
    }
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($credits as $credit)
    {{ $credit->recipient->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by changing in my `Credit` Model:

```
public function recipient() {}
```

into

```
public function user() {}
```